# Is there a Vivox standalone application for non-gamers?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am wondering if someone can communicate with players with an external vivox standalone application.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely can as the Vivox SDK can be included in any type of Project not just Unreal Engine.

This would be better asked through one of their official channels.

https://developer.vivox.com/

Vivox is a Unity Technology, so their support is handled on the Unity Forums.

https://unity.com/products/vivox